# CakePHP - unit testing admin view

Tags: cakephp, simpletest

How can I do CakePHP unit testing for views that is password protected?

I see an article about admin controller but not views http://mark-story.com/posts/view/testing-cakephp-controllers-the-hard-way

So basically right now my assert is failing because of the password page.

```
$this->get($this->baseurl . '/admin/items');
$this->assertText('Title');
```

Thanks,
Tee

Comment: I had the same problem, check the answer here:

[how can I test view where authentication is required, with cakePHP and SimpleTest][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337934/how-can-i-test-view-where-authentication-is-required-with-cakephp-and-simpletest

Answer (score 0):

You may have to mock or stub the authcomponent for your tests to always authenticate users. A bit of googling turns this up

[Real-world testing of CakePHP controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246666/real-world-testing-of-cakephp-controllers)